# Bug with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview

I'm writing this post because I have a bug with my ScrollViews
As soon as I start to scroll, it goes like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayrKjQI0zSQ
And it does like this for every scroll view that I have in my app, I didn't find a solution for that
Can you help me please ?
Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.streetworkoutarrasFR.view.OurTeamActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_our_team"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="ADRIEN" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/adrien" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_adrien"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:text="STEPH"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="477dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/steph" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_steph"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:text="OMAR"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="477dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/omar" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_omar"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:text="PIERRE"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="477dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/pierre" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_pierre"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:text="GAUTIER"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="477dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gautier" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_gautier"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:text="ALEX"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="477dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/alex_martiniquais" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_alex"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="BAPTISTE"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bapt"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_bapt"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="ALEX"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                android:src="@drawable/alex_demailly"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_alex2"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="BEN"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ben"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_ben"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="HUGO"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                android:src="@drawable/hugo"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_hugo"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="KEVIN" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/kevinou" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_kevin"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />

            

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="BENJAMIN" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/benji" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_benji"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-11dp" />




        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I don't know what to give you more
Thanks in advance,
Steph

Comment: What are the negative values about? I don't use Android Studio but they look like they could be problematic.

Comment: @RobotHead `tools` namespace doesn't affect runtime

Comment: Does it even compile? you have `app:layout_constraintXXX`  without constrint layout ... also puting `app:layout_behavior` to old `ScrollView` also smelly

Answer (score 0):

@Selvin I deleted the layout behavior and all constraints but it remained the same
Also I forgot to say that this layout is contained in another layout, here it is:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.streetworkoutarrasFR.view.OurTeamActivity">

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   <include layout="@layout/content_our_team" />



   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />





</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, and sorry for being so late!

Recently I got the same bug, and was very scared of it, because there were not even a hint of what it could be

Your post helped me to go further, and after one week of search, I finally found, and as your background have a custom color, I think you have the same problem as me

If the style in theme.xml contains some valor in the background, the error occurs, this only happens in android 9 and lesser, the bug can be corrected, if yours is the same cause, by changing the value from "background" to "backgroundTint"

I hope this helped, probably not as it has been 11 months, but I couldn't stand not giving an answer, as you were the only one I found with the same issue

Comment: No need to add things like *Sorry*, just add the answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue when the style set as the theme for the application had the following element:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

On some devices, ScrollViews would show the same scrolling artifacts as in your video, even when the ScrollView or the containing layout set `android:background` to a color resource.

The solution was to change the theme by setting `android:windowBackground` to a color resource. You can also set themes for specific Activities in your project's `AndroidManifest.xml` if you only want to change the theme for certain screens.